# Integrate SwiftLint with Swift package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swiftlint

I created a Swift Package and would like to integrate SwiftLint with that package. since there is no ".xcodeproj" is any other option available?
FYI, I use the code for iOS platform

Thank you,

Comment: You want to distribute swiftlint with your released package, is that what you are saying?

Comment: @joakim Danielson. Not for the released package, I was thinking to have a staging target for this integeration.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, theres no way to do that currently. A workaround would be to create an example project and add the swiftlint to the build phase of the that example project while giving the path to lint as the root of the directory.

This proposal has been accepted, so we can look for it in the next swift update or something https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0303-swiftpm-extensible-build-tools.md